# Is it possible to use data grouping in Highcharts without Highstocks?

Tags: highcharts

I am struggling with a quite simple issue. I am trying to regroup data in Highcharts (my backend sometimes send me several data points for the same day). This feature exists in Highstock but does not seem to work in Highcharts.

I am wondering if this is normal or if I do something wrong, the official documentation is not really clear.

Further explanation: I want to have only one data point / day containing the sum of the maybe several daily points. I cannot use Highstocks seems I need other highcharts features and did not buy Highstock license anyway.

```
dataGrouping: {
        approximation: "sum",
        units: [[
            'day',
            [1]
        ]]
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sikwan/u120weyL/

Thanks

Comment: Only Highstock contains `dataGrouping` feature. Just to be clear: Highstock contains all features from Highcharts, just use Highcharts constructor when including Highstock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided in comments. Here it is :

@pawel-fus
Only Highstock contains dataGrouping feature. Just to be clear: Highstock contains all features from Highcharts, just use Highcharts constructor when including Highstock.

Thanks again Pawel